# P5.js not loading sound

Tags: processing, p5.js

I am trying to load an mp3 files (according to the examples) but I am getting

`Unable to load bg.mp3. 
The request status was: 0 () 
The error stack trace includes: loadSound`

I have referenced my problem to this Github issue https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/141 but I am unable to find a solution. 
Also, I am using Brackets editor which starts a local server and opens a new Chrome instance.

```
let mySound;
function preload() {
  soundFormats('mp3', 'ogg');
  mySound = loadSound("bg.mp3");
}

function setup(){
   createCanvas(displayWidth,displayHeight);
   mySound.setVolume(0.1);
   mySound.play();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Strange, the [Sound: Load and Play Sound example](https://editor.p5js.org/p5/sketches/bFFYRgOCfel) seems to work fine.

The error seems to [point to on an XHR load error](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/blob/master/src/soundfile.js#L257), but it's unclear why.

It's worth trying the [full version of `loadSound()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile/loadSound) including the error callback:`loadSound(path, [successCallback], [errorCallback], [whileLoading])`.
Hopefully the `errorCallback` details will help solve the problem
e.g.

```
let mySound;
function onSoundLoadSuccess(e){
   console.log("load sound success",e);
}
function onSoundLoadError(e){
   console.log("load sound error",e);
}
function onSoundLoadProgress(e){
   console.log("load sound progress",e);
}
function preload() {
  soundFormats('mp3', 'ogg');
  mySound = loadSound("bg.mp3",onSoundLoadSuccess,onSoundLoadError,onSoundLoadProgress);
}

function setup(){
   createCanvas(displayWidth,displayHeight);
   mySound.setVolume(0.1);
   mySound.play();
}
```

Also try to navigate to the web server Brackets launches and access the file manually.
(e.g. http://localhost:BRACKETS_HTTP_PORT_HERE/bg.mp3). If everything is ok (bg.mp3 is in the same folder as the index.html file), your browser should load and display the default audio playback controls.

It's worth noting there are many other http servers you could try, here a few examples:

1. if you're on OSX you can use Python's HTTP Server (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in python 2 or `python -m http.server`)
2. if you use node.js there' an http-server module (e.g. `npm install http-server` then `http-server` in your project folder)
3. Apache variants (depending on OS, MAMP/WAMP/XAMPP, etc.), though might be overkill

Answer (score 1):

The **quick fix** for anyone having this issue is to use a `Local web server`. (mamp/xamp/local etc). Then reference it in the preload/setup

```
sound = loadSound('http://localhost/audio.mp3', loaded);
```

The documentation does state -

> you will need the p5.sound library and a running local server